# How to give acces to Reports via SQL

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a large number of reports where access is controlled on Report level and not folder level.

While one method is to use Server Groups, then this is not the way the setup currently is. Although that would be a good way to manage it.

Using

```
select C.UserName, D.RoleName, D.Description, E.Path, E.Name 
from dbo.PolicyUserRole A
inner join dbo.Policies B on A.PolicyID = B.PolicyID
inner join dbo.Users C on A.UserID = C.UserID
inner join dbo.Roles D on A.RoleID = D.RoleID
inner join dbo.Catalog E on A.PolicyID = E.PolicyID
Where C.UserName = 'XXX'
order by C.UserName
```

I can get all the reports a user has access to.

So I thought I could generate an SQL statement that can grant access to a user to the same reports as another user has access too, or just a given report.

But I can't seem to wrap my head around how many Places I have to insert data to make this happen.

Does anyone have a solution to this, or a starting point.

Without wanting to destroy something, I thought I could use SQL to grant access to specific reports.

Edit: 
It seems I am not the only one wanting to do this:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/273420db-a506-47bb-9c13-f360e44996bd/bulk-add-users

However it seams the tables are not officially documented, further there are problems concerning the structure and inhertitence of rights, which leaves the RS.exe the only method short of using the webinterface to give users or add user rights to a specific report or folder.

Comment: This seems to be the only way of added new users programmically without breaking ReportServer.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bryanke/archive/2004/03/17/91736.aspx